# Generate a simple 2nd level dropdown menu with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown

I have a top_menu and a almenu named table. I want a simple dropdown menu by the menu id-s. The problem with this code, that it echo-s out the "Információk" menuitem 3 times, and puts into them the 3 menuitem from the almenu table.

[image]

[image]

The code does now: (It puts out 3 times the Információk menuitem from the top_menu table as new menuitems in the navbar)
Informáciok (Alapadatok),  Informáciok (Kollégium), Informáciok (Osztályok)

And not: Informáciok (Alapadatok, Kollégium, Osztályok) (This is what i want)

```
<?php
                $menu_sql = 
                "
                    SELECT 

                        top_menu.top_menu_nev,
                        top_menu.top_menu_seo,
                        top_menu.top_menu_dropdown,
                        almenu.almenu_nev,
                        almenu.almenu_seo

                    FROM top_menu LEFT JOIN almenu ON top_menu.top_menu_id = almenu.almenu_parent

                    WHERE top_menu.menu_status = 1 AND top_menu.menu_position = 1

                    ORDER BY top_menu.top_menu_sorrend ASC

                ";
                $get_menu = mysqli_query($kapcs, $menu_sql) or die(mysqli_error($kapcs));
                while($top_menu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_menu))
                {
                    if($top_menu['top_menu_dropdown'] == 0 )
                    {
                        echo '<li><a href="'.$host.'/'.$top_menu['top_menu_seo'].'" title="'.$top_menu['top_menu_nev'].'" class="top_menu_to_link">'.$top_menu['top_menu_nev'].'</a></li>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<li class="dropdown">';                       
                            echo '<a href="#" title="" class="top_menu_to_link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'.$top_menu['top_menu_nev'].'</a>'; 
                            echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                                echo '<li><a href="'.$host.'/'.$top_menu['almenu_seo'].'" title="'.$top_menu['almenu_nev'].'" class="top_menu_to_link">'.$top_menu['almenu_nev'].'</a></li>';
                            echo '</ul>';                   
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you loop thru the whole nav over and over again.

The following code lets you generate new li items:

```
            echo '<li class="dropdown">';                       
            echo '<a href="#" title="" class="top_menu_to_link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'.$top_menu['top_menu_nev'].'</a>'; 
            echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';

            $get_menu = mysqli_query($kapcs, $menu_sql) or die(mysqli_error($kapcs));
            while($top_menu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_menu))
            {
                if($top_menu['top_menu_dropdown'] == 0 )
                {
                    echo '<li><a href="'.$host.'/'.$top_menu['top_menu_seo'].'" title="'.$top_menu['top_menu_nev'].'" class="top_menu_to_link">'.$top_menu['top_menu_nev'].'</a></li>';
                }
                else
                {
                            echo '<li><a href="'.$host.'/'.$top_menu['almenu_seo'].'" title="'.$top_menu['almenu_nev'].'" class="top_menu_to_link">'.$top_menu['almenu_nev'].'</a></li>';

                }
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</li>';
```

Comment: But i dont need echo '<li class="dropdown">';   at every menuitem. Not every menuitem will be dropdown.

Comment: Can someone help me?